# Node Environment is throwing a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a node backend that is attempting to establish a connection to mongodb cluster via the mongoose package.

When using nodemon my node.js/express server runs however it never establishes a connection to mongodb and after a few seconds, throws a **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms**

I have literally no idea how to solve this issue, apparently i didn't handle a promise rejection in my logic, can someone help me with this issue?

```
const express = require("express");
// const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

//cors middleware
app.use(cors);
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
//useNewUrlParser parsing mongodb string
mongoose.connect(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true
});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("MONGODB connection established");
});

const exereciseRouter = require("./routes/exercises");
const usersRouter = require("./routes/users");

app.use("/exercises", exereciseRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server listening on", port);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `useUnifiedTopology: true` from mongoDB connection

this issue is already discussed [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8180)